# Contents are not shown without resizing the windows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I made a small application to open a file and show the contents of opened file in some JTextField and JLabels. I can get all the contents and fill in the TextFields and Labels but the problem is these JLabels and JTextFields are not shown untill and unless I resize(even a little) the windows. I want my contents to be shown straight away. What do I need to do for this.

WL

here is a piece of code to initialize the panel and adding it to scrollpane

```
        panel = new JPanel();

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

In the actionlistener of open button I got the following code

```
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileReader.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                String filePath = file.getPath();
               // if(panel.isDisplayable()==true)panel.
                if(scrollPane != null){
                    //panel.removeAll();    
                this.remove(scrollPane);
              //  scrollPane.add(panel);
                    //panel.add(panel);
                    //panel.validate();
                //panel.repaint();

                }
                //pass the file to XMLparser
                xmlParsing = new XMLParsing(filePath); 

                panel = new JPanel();


                panel=fill();
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();

          scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

                add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                //add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                saveButton.setEnabled(true);
                saveasButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Post come code please. http://sscce.org

Comment: In case there is any confusion, the code snippet posted is not an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding all the components call

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

of container

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I am assuming that you must have forgot to put the code that is responsible for creating and displaying your code in the Event Dispatcher Thread.

For Example :

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
       {
           public void run()
           {
               /* Put the method or code, which is responsible for 
                * creating and displaying your GUI, here.
                * That can be the issue too, what you are facing.
                */
           }
       });
}
```

And do use validate() and repaint() methods once done changing your components.
Hope this might help in some way.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Gapandeep, I was missing validate and repait. now all good :)

Comment: @waqas : Glad you made it through the obstacle.  :-) Regards

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
but the problem is these JLabels and JTextFields are not shown untill 
and unless I resize(even a little) the windows. I want my contents to 
be shown straight away.
```

some issues could be

- setVisible(true) as last line in the Swing GUI constructor, check and remove for duplicates
- main method must be wrapped into invokeLater

for example,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BorderPanels extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BorderPanels() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());// set LayoutManager
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        Border eBorder = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(eBorder, "70pct"));
        gbc.gridx = gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 70;
        add(panel1, gbc); // add compoenet to the COntentPane
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(eBorder, "30pct"));
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 30;
        gbc.weighty = 30;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        add(panel2, gbc); // add component to the COntentPane
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // important
        pack();
        setVisible(true); // important
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { // important

            public void run() {
                BorderPanels borderPanels = new BorderPanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2)

```
small application to open a file and show the contents of opened file 
in some JTextField and JLabels
```

there should be second area that your GUI doesn't show any JComponent or without value

- check is Stream from File end succesfully, wrap FIleStream to try - catch - finally block, add to the catch block printStackTrace for displaying Exception
- in this form you reading data during Main thread and all GUI waiting for Stream ended

3)

- create empty GUI without any value in the JTextFIelds
- diplay this GUI
- starting [Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)
- redirect FileStream to the Runnable#Thread or SwingWorker
- hide Splash Screen on FileStream ended
- add values to JTextFields

Comment: +1 for some wonderful tips to work on. Might will help me soon :-)  Regards

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you've added your components and what layout you've used, a call to layout.pack() could solve your issue. Maybe adding a code snippet could also ease the job on helping you :D.

Answer (score 0):

you should call `.repaint()` method of JFrame

Comment: I don't think that calling repaint() is the best thing to do (as the paint method is called anyway by the GUI Thread). The layout should paint correctly if the layouts have been used correctly and the code which does the update is "invoked" correctly. But in absence of a snippet...